# Calling executable files from JSP

Tags: jsp

Is there anything similar to php's exec() function in jsp?

I'm running Websphere App server in my Windows machine. I would like to call some .exe files when a link is clicked in my jsp page.

Please tell me if any function is available in jsp that helps in executing an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you are :

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmd[]={"cmd.exe", "/C", "c:\\windows\\paint.exe"};
rt.exec(cmd);
```

Comment: If you must use Runtime.exec, please do read this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html.  You'll save yourself a lot of heartache.

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea.  I don't have to know much about what you're doing to advise that you reconsider.  JSPs are for view, not for calling executable code somewhere on the app server.

Comment: Ok, I'm using JSP's for view only...I want to summarize the tasks that I execute via command line by providing links/buttons in the jsp page. I dont really want to see the output of the execution, just that I need to call the command line multiple times with different parameters. SO I thought I'll build a Servlet and generate the required parametrs and call the command line. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

JSPs can effectively do anything Java can do - Java [can exec](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html?l=new) an external program.

You can use

```
 <%
     // some Java here
 %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've thought that!